# How can I create an `__m128i` datatype with Frida?

Tags: ida, c++, frida

I'm working on reversing a c++ binary and it has a function that I want to call with Frida.
Here's the function signature from IDA: `const __m128i *__fastcall sub_0123(__m128i * a1);`

It doesn't seem possible to create an `__m128i` datatype in a Frida script. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

For reference, I am on android and this is an Intel x64 intrinsic. Info on the datatype here: http://portal.nacad.ufrj.br/online/intel/compiler_c/common/core/GUID-7478B278-2240-44D8-B396-1DC508E3656E.htm

Comment: You should give more details on what the datataype `__m128i` is, is it a struct, a class or what else? What platform are you on (Windows, Linux, MacOS, Android, iOS)?

Comment: I am on android. As far as I can tell, it's an intel intrinsic. I found this link about them: http://portal.nacad.ufrj.br/online/intel/compiler_c/common/core/GUID-7478B278-2240-44D8-B396-1DC508E3656E.htm